# flutter internationalization using dynamic string in json file

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-intl

So far I was using dynamic strings as shown in the solution of this post:
[Flutter internationalization - Dynamic strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278035/flutter-internationalization-dynamic-strings)

Here's an example:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).userAge(18)
```

And on AppLocalizations.dart:

```
userAge(age) => Intl.message(
  "My age is $age",
  name: "userAge",
  args: [age]);
// Return "My age is 18"
```

But then I read this article about flutter internationalization: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2
Which shows how to localize using json files as resource files for the strings. It looks way more convenient so I prefer to use this method, but don't know how to get strings from json file with dynamic values.

Any solution?

Answer (score 10):

To get the string with the dynamic value from JSON file you can use

```
final age = 18 //user input.
final ageString = 'user_age'
                   .localisedString()
                   .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\${age}'), age)
```

> en.json

```
{
  "user_age": "My age is ${age}",
  "user_name_age": "My name is ${name} and age is ${age}"
}
```

> string_extension.dart

```
extension Localisation on String {
  String localisedString() {
    return stringBy(this) ?? '';
  }
}
```

Also, you could do something like,

```
  String localisedString(Map<String, String> args) {
      String str = localisedString();
      args.forEach((key, value) { 
        str = str.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\${'+key+'}'), value);
      });
      return str;
  }
  
  //usecase
  final userName = 'Spider Man'
  final age = '18'
  final nameAgeString = 'user_name_age'.localisedString({'name': userName, 'age': age})
```

> app_localisation.dart

```
Map<String, dynamic> _language;

String stringBy(String key) => _language[key] as String ?? 'null';

class AppLocalisationDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate {
  const AppLocalisationDelegate();

  // override the following method if you want to specify the locale you are supporting.
  final _supportedLocale = ['en'];
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => _supportedLocale.contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future load(Locale locale) async {
    String jsonString = await rootBundle
        .loadString("assets/strings/${locale.languageCode}.json");

    _language = jsonDecode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(_language.toString());
    return SynchronousFuture<AppLocalisationDelegate>(
        AppLocalisationDelegate());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(AppLocalisationDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a folder say `json` in your `assets` directory. Put your language files in it.

   ```
   assets
     json
      - en.json // for English 
      - ru.json  // for Russian
   ```
2. Now in `en.json`, write your string, for example.

   ```
   {
     "myAge": "My age is"
   }
   ```

   Similarly, in `ru.json`,

   ```
   {
     "myAge": "Мой возраст"
   }
   ```
3. Add this to the `pubspec.yaml` file (mind the spaces)

   ```
   flutter:

     uses-material-design: true

     assets:
       - assets/json/
   ```

   Run `flutter pub get`

---

Initial work done. Let's move to the code side.

Copy this boilerplate code in your file:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> language;

class AppLocalizations {
  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  String getText(String key) => language[key];

  String userAge(int age) => '${getText('myAge')} $age';
}

class AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en', 'ru'].contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    final string = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    language = json.decode(string);
    return SynchronousFuture<AppLocalizations>(AppLocalizations());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Set up few things in `MaterialApp` widget:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale('ru'), // switch between "en" and "ru" to see effect
      localizationsDelegates: [const AppLocalizationsDelegate()],
      supportedLocales: [const Locale('en'), const Locale('ru')],
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now, you can simply use above delegate:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var age = AppLocalizations.of(context).userAge(18);
    // prints "My age is 18" for 'en' and "Мой возраст 18" for 'ru' locale. 
    print(age); 

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that I need the placeholder of the value inside the resource file (because this is the file I send to the translator). A good solution I found  is using the easy_localization package. I succeed with it to translate from json file but not from an XML file. I opened a new post on this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448388/cant-get-string-values-from-xml-file-using-the-flutter-easy-localization-packag)

Answer (score 4):

I've tried various solutions to implement localization, and the best I've come across is the Flutter Intl plugin for [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) or [Android Studio/IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) made by [Localizely.com](https://localizely.com) (not affiliated).

With it, basically you install the plugin using the marketplace/plugin library, then initialize for your project using the menu option. This creates a default english locale in lib/l10n/intl_en.arb (which sounds scary but is actually just JSON) and sets up all the scaffolding for the internationalization in `lib/generated`.

You also have to add the following to your dependencies.

```yaml
flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

You can then add keys to this file and they'll be automatically available in your app, by importing `generated/l10n.dart` which contains a class called S.

To get flutter to use it, wherever it is that you initialize your MaterialApp, make sure to pass `S.delegate` into MaterialApp's localizationsDelegates parameter (most likely as part of an array with `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate`, `GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate`, and possibly `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate`.) You also have to add `S.delegate.supportedLocales` to MaterialApp's `supportedLocales`.

To add more locales, use the option in the menu (in intellij at least) or simply create more intl_.arb files, and the plugin will automatically recognize this and set up the relevant code.

Say you have an intl_en file with the following:

```
{ "name": "Name" }
```

You'd then use `S.of(context).name` to use the string in your code.

All this is more eloquently explained on [localizely](https://localizely.com/flutter-localization-workflow)'s website.

---

Now, to use keys in these .arb files, you simply have to wrap it in {...}. So for example:

```
{ "choose1OfNumOptions": "Choose 1 of {numoptions} options" }
```

would lead to a usage of `S.of(context).choose1OfNumOptions(numOptions);`. I don't know that the plugin supports the full [ARB specification](https://github.com/google/app-resource-bundle/wiki/ApplicationResourceBundleSpecification) but it does support at least the basics.

Also, I'm not using Localizely but it seems like it'd be a pretty useful way to manage the translations and the plugin integrates automatically, although I think it's also pretty horrendously overpriced - at least for my app, which happens to have a ton of text. I actually just have a google sheet where I store all my translations, and when it's time to update it I download it as a .tsv and wrote a simple little parser to write out to the .arb files.

Answer (score 3):

## flutter_localizations:

### app_en.arb:

```
{
  "contactDetailsPopupEmailCopiedMessage": "Copied {email} to clipboard",
  "@contactDetailsPopupEmailCopiedMessage": {
    "description": "Message being displayed in a snackbar upon long-clicking email in contact details popup",
    "placeholders": {
      "email": {
        "type": "String",
        "example": "example@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### app_localizations.dart:

```
abstract class AppLocalizations {
  /// Message being displayed in a snackbar upon long-clicking email in contact details popup
  ///
  /// In en, this message translates to:
  /// **'Copied {email} to clipboard'**
  String contactDetailsPopupEmailCopiedMessage(String email);
}
```

### usage:

```
l10n.contactDetailsPopupEmailCopiedMessage("example@gmail.com")
```

For more details take a look [here](https://stepwise.pl/2021/04/15/flutter-internationalization-with-arb-files/).

Comment: What about multiple dynamic args in a single string?

Comment: Cool, you can do that by adding multiple arguments...